# write a test for scala code

Tags: scala, unit-testing, tdd, scalatest

I am learning how to do unit tests with scalatest , but I have some basic questions as I am learning Scala/Scalatest 
I wrote one scala script which has one scala object with several methods. My question is as follows: Should I write one unit test for the whole Scala object or should I write a test per function. 
For example I wrote the following function : 
Do you know how to write a test with scala test for this specific function:

```
def dataProcessing (input: List[String]) = {



val Data = input.map(_.trim).filter(x => !(x contains "$")).filter(line => Seq("11", "18").exists(s => line.contains(s))).map(elt => elt.replaceAll("""[\t\p{Zs}\.\$]+""", " ")).map(_.split("\\s+")).map(x => (x(1),x(1),x(3),dataLength(x(3)),dataType(x(3))))

 return Data
}
```

Finally I am trying to use the test driven design best practices but still don't know how to proceed to write tests before writing code , Any tips how to proceed to be compliant with these practices.

Many thanks

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I would avoid writing such long lines. Either define some intermediate `val`s or at least split each method to a new line.

Comment: Another possibility is to define private helper methods to do some of the individual steps. These should be named to clearly describe what they do.

Comment: Also, consider defining a case class to hold your output, rather than returning a 5-tuple. Something like this: `case class Descriptor(firstName: String, middleName: String, lastName: String, age: Int, jobTitle: String)`

Comment: As for the TDD part of the question - the entire idea behind TDD is that you know what success looks like before you start the code.  So when you thought you were going to define `dataProcessing` you probably knew what your input to it and what your output from it should look like.  With that knowledge, you should be able to write a test to say when I feed it X, I get Y as a result.  So you set up your test as @tilde outlined in his answer and then you watch it fail - then write just enough code to make it pass.

Answer (score 2):

In general, when you define a class or object, you should write tests for the methods someone using that class should call, and the other methods should be private. If you find yourself wanting to make methods public, just so they can be tested, consider moving them to a separate class or object.

There are a lot of testing styles supported by scala test. Personally, I like `WordSpec`. A basic test in progress would look like this:

```
class MyTest extends WordSpec with Matchers {
  "My Object" should {
    "process descriptors" when {
      "there is one input" in {
        val input = List("2010 Ford Mustang")

        val output = MyObject.descriptorProcessing(input)

        output should have length 1
        output.head shouldBe()
      }

      "there are two inputs" in pendingUntilFixed {
        val input = List("Abraham Joe Lincoln, 34, President",
                         "George Ronald Washington, 29, President")

        val output = MyObject.descriptorProcessing(input)

        output should have length 2
        output.head shouldBe()
      }
    }

    "format descriptors" when {
      "there is one input" in pending
    }
  }
}
```

I've used two features of scalatest that enable TDD, `pendingUntilFixed` and `pending`.

`pendingUntilFixed` lets you write a test for code that hasn't been implemented yet, or isn't working correctly yet. As long an assertion in the test fails, the test is ignored and displayed in yellow output. Once all the assertions pass, the test fails, letting you know that you can turn it on. This enables TDD, while allowing your build to pass before work is completed.

`pending` is a marker saying "I'm going to write a test for this, but I haven't gotten to it yet". I use this a lot, as it allows me to write an outline for my tests, then go back and fill them in.